# Copy paste over Citrix loses formatting

Tags: tinymce, clipboard, citrix

I have a html table (you may insert the table using Outlook menu, add some color, text bolding ext.) in Outlook and I try to copy and paste it to an application in a Citrix session.

I am using TinyMCE's clipboard viewer application (https://static.ephox.com/clipboard/clipboardtest.html) to tell the difference between pasting the content on my (local) laptop and the remove session.

On the local device, I get html content, but on the remote session, I get a content which is in Microsoft "RTF" format.

Please note that the "RTF" format content can only be recognized by Microsoft products such as Word, Outlook, etc., so if I paste the same to other applications (such as TinyMCE's fiddle for tiny editor at https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/) in a Citrix session, the pasted content may lose some formatting, only very limited html of the table may be kept.